# Do I need to run a server to achieve database-like functionality?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010

I'm currently trying to develop a program which stores lots of data, similar to an address book, I suppose, with the intent that new data will be periodically added to the program over time.

I know that I *could* set up a SQL server, and have the program interface with that, but if I want to share my program with other people, I can't guarantee that they'd have access to the server, or that they can set up a server of their own to hold the data.

I *also* know that I could simply hard-code all of the data into instantiated objects, but that is inelegant, and promises to be incredibly irritating to alter or maintain.

Is there someway I could design the program in such a way that it maintains a database-like structure, yet has no reliance on external programs (such as a SQL server)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You can use XML. XML can be also used as a datasource for ASP.NET components, just like a database.

Comment: Or You could use SQL Compact edition, which can be embedded into application if I am correct (never done that before).

Comment: I think XML is the way I want to go. Now to find out how to *use* it.

Answer (score 2):

"SQLite is a software library that implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine."

http://www.sqlite.org/

Comment: Should also note it is free, and distributable (db files)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a flat file database like SQLite which is linked in on compile and could be distributed with your code.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

1. Use flat-file database like [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) ([ADO.NET provider](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/))
2. Save your data into a file in some format like XML or CSV, or use binary serialization (or something more elaborate if you don't want to have all the data in memory)
3. Have a public SQL server accessible from the internet

Comment: MS Access is not different to full-fledged SQL database in this regard – the users have to have it installed.

Comment: I think it's not necessary for users to have Access installed, they need only Jet driver for Access.

Answer (score 0):

Of course these is always [SQL Server express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/) from MS for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

**no** you do not neet a server. the most flexibel solution would be to use [NHibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/343.html) with [FluentNHibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/).

There are different drivers for different databases like SQlite, MsAccess and also for Server like MsSql, Oracle, ....